# Brave browser error: unsupported command-line flag

Tags: 18.04, security, snap

I am getting this error message

> "You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --no-sandbox.  Security will suffer."

[image: screenshot]

How can i correct this error?  This is on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 
edit: I found this discussion of the problem [on Brave Community](https://community.brave.com/t/unsupported-command-line-flag-no-sandbox/40069)

Comment: From the link you posted, it appears that the browser's developers are aware of the issue (across distros).

Comment: The process is runn with `/snap/brave/44/opt/brave.com/brave/brave --no-sandbox` fnot in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/brave_brave.desktop`) even [the installation instructions](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/docs/linuxInstall.md) warn against doing that. [**Is a bug**](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/1986). There is a workaround enabling kernel namspaces which should be [strongly avoided](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/security).